# wordpress taxonomy issue?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, product

I am having an issue with the product permalinks on a website I have been asked to fix.

website page where links are broken: http://fallenangelbakery.com/menu/cupcakes/

There is a product-types taxonomy created which gets to the above page ok. However, the links to the individual products do not work. When editing the products, the permalink and the shortlink dont work.

loop code in taxonomy-product-types.php

```
<div class="cw">
<div class="c">
        <div class="cs"></div>
        <h1><?= single_tag_title( '', false ) ?></h1>
        <div class="cds"><?= category_description()?></div> 
        <div class="full">
            <? if($wp_query->post_count < 8 && $wp_query->post_count > 4 || $wp_query->post_count == 3){
                    $class = 'medium';
                } else if($wp_query->post_count <= 4){
                    $class = 'large';
                } else {
                    $class = 'small';
                }
            ?>          
            <ul class="product-list <?=$class?>">
            <? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>" title="<? the_title(); ?>">
                    <div class="frame top gb"></div>
                        <div class="frame right gb"></div>
                            <? the_post_thumbnail( 'fab-'.$class.'-image' ); ?>
                        <div class="frame bottom gb"></div>
                    <div class="frame left gb"></div>

                    <span class="title"><? the_title(); ?></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <? endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="divider category"><span class="stars gb"></span></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="cb gb"></div>
```

the taxonomy is associated with "products" and we get products and product types as menu items in the wp-admin

taxonomy: product-types
label of taxonomy: products
slug: menu
query var: product-types
singular name: product-type

in order to get to the single product i have created a file called taxonomy-product.php.

can anyone give an idea why the product permalink doesnt work at all... even when trying to preview the page in wp-admin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-taxonomy-manager/

Many thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried regenerating your permalinks?

Comment: The website looks delicious by the way :3 - I agree with @celeriko - try going to Settings -> Permalinks and resaving them which will regenerate them and hopefully get your website working.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I have tried that already but no joy. Its frustrating as the shortlink and preview options dont work when editing the actual products!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

I believe this is a problem with the taxonomy not being public.

Comment: hi and thanks for the response. the plugin that is being used is This is an Easy to use Plugin to Create, Customize, Manage Taxonomies as well as Manage its Custom Meta Fields. Now add images to category/tags.

== Description ==
This plugin is an **Easy to use Taxonomy Manager** to Customize Taxonomies and its Custom Fields, with great UI.
**[Download now!](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/ultimate-taxonomy-manager.zip)**. I thought the plugin would autoregister new taxonomies or is that not the case.